# Retrieving information from QLineEdit as soon as there is input?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit

I have the following PyQT code:

```
self.datestartbox = QLineEdit(self) # Create a textbox
self.dateendbox = QLineEdit(self) # Create a textbox
```

How can I get the user input as soon there is text in the fields? At the moment I can only get it when user clicks a button and then use

```
self.datestartbox.text()
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To do that you have to use:

```
self.datestartbox.textChanged.connect(function_to_call_when_text_change)
```